# After using "à laquelle", should you say "à faire" with accord rather than "(de) faire"?

Tags: grammaire

In conversation, I just said:

> La dernière chose **à laquelle** je m'attendais, c’est **à** tomber sur toi dans cette station balnéaire ! Franchement, de tous les endroits où je l’aurais pu !

Or should I have used "de" instead or added nothing there? After all, you usually use "(de) + infinitive" to express the idea of "to + infinitive".

> La dernière chose **à laquelle** je m'attendais, c’est **de** tomber sur toi ...
>
> La dernière chose **à laquelle** je m'attendais, c’est tomber sur toi ...

---

And what about when "à" is followed by a noun instead of a verb? Should I omit this "à"?

> Ce **à quoi** je fais le plus attention dans mon régime alimentaire, c’est **à** la quantité de sucre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, idiomatic:

> *La dernière chose à laquelle je m'attendais, **c’était**<sup>*</sup> **de tomber** sur toi…*

Dubious, might be heard in lazy spoken French:

> *La dernière chose à laquelle je m'attendais, **c’était tomber** sur toi…*

Incorrect:

> *La dernière chose à laquelle je m'attendais, **c’était à tomber** sur toi…*

What would work with *à tomber* is for example:

> *Tu devrais essayer cette recette, **c'est à tomber** par terre !*

Note also that *Franchement, de tous les endroits où je l’aurais pu !* is not very clear/idomatic and *je l'aurais pu* is too formal to be used in such a sentence. I would maybe write:

> *Franchement, quand je pense à tous les endroits où ça aurait pu arriver avant !*

or

> *Franchement, quand je pense aux autres endroits où ça aurait eu plus de chance d'arriver !*

<sup>* Thanks to @machasu for the tense point.</sup>

Comment: « ***Ce à quoi*** je fais le plus attention dans mon régime alimentaire, c’est ***à*** la quantité de sucre. » Hi. What do you think of this usage, then? The difference being "c'est à + ***noun***" instead of "c'est à + verb".

Comment: *C'est à* + ***verb*** is possible. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jlliagre except on one point but I couldn't only comment as I have less that 50 reputation.

The one point being the sequence of tenses (*concordance des temps*). It is really important that you stick to one tense in a single sentence in the written langage (if you have to pass a test, for example), but it is also what would come naturally to my mind should I have to speak such a sentence.

So for both correct cases, you'd rather say :

*La dernière chose à laquelle je m'attendais, c’était de tomber sur toi…*

or

*La dernière chose à laquelle je m'attendais, c’était tomber sur toi…*

The mix between past tense and present tense feels really unnatural to me, and would grant you at least some comment, at worst some deduction on your mark in an academic environment.